Laravel9 Request::get() adds two spaces after the value
I am little confused what is going on but as I try to call $request->get() I get the value with two spaces at the end of the string which is invalid according the validation. The method is GET but I dont thing it should be relevant to this issue. The request comes from Postman and I am pretty sure the value is without spaces. Can somebody tell me if it is possible?
